# PageReference Keep Page Original Text Case (Upper and Lower)

Tags: apex, visualforce, pagereference, url, string

This may be been asked before (I couldn't locate it), but given the below example. I need to create a url for a custom field, but the case changes. Is there a simple way around this to keep the original VisualForce page text case. I know Apex is case-insensitive, so not sure sure if there is a simple fix for this.

Let's say the page is called TestPage.

```
PageReference testPage = Page.TestPage;
testPage.getParameters().put('param', 'value');
// This will return '/apex/testpage?param=value' as opposed to '/apex/TestPage?param=value'
System.debug(testPage.getUrl());
```

Comment: have you tried instantiating the page reference like `new PageReference('/apex/TestPage')`? If I remember correctly, this preserved lower/upper case for me.

Comment: Why do you care?

Comment: @AdrianLarson I don't. The client does.

Comment: Then you should ask them why it makes a difference.

Comment: @AdrianLarson I like the way you think. It shouldn't matter.